# At what base is square root of 120 natural number

Tags: number-systems

I got this problem i need to solve: 
At what base b, where b>2 , (120)<sub>b</sub> equals x<sup>2</sup>, where x is in decimal number system? I need to find all bases b, and i need to see the process of finding answer, so i can do it myself.

Comment: Hint: $(120)_b=b^2+2b=(b+1)^2-1$.

Answer (score 1):

$(120)_b = b^2+2b$

$b^2+2b$ can never be a perfect square as $b^2+2b+1$ is (except for $b=0$).

Comment: That is what i thought as well, but can that be presented as valid proof, or do i need to find other way to prove it?

Comment: Yes. Or include Apple's hint and express it as $(b+1)^2-1$ to show that it is always one less than a perfect square.